# How to check if binary data(Image) is already saved in core data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have core data table named ActionImage with fields image and actionid now I want to check if new image that I am going to save is already saved image with actionid. I have this code to check other values but it is not working with binary data

```
class func valueExistWhere(key:String, value:Any) -> Bool {
        let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<ActionImage> = ActionImage.fetchRequest()
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "\(key)=\(value)")
        var data:[ActionImage] = []
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
        fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
        do{
            data = try CoreDataStack.getContext().fetch(fetchRequest)

            if(data.count > 0)
            {
                return true
            }
            else
            {
                return false
            }
        }
        catch{
            print("Error: \(error)")
            return false
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The predicate format is simply a string.  There is a strict definition for how it is constructed, and cannot just drop in values and expect it to work (though it often does).

change

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "\(key)=\(value)")
```

to

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K = %@", key, value)
```